# Matrix of objects, accessing the fields

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have this class

```
class cell
{
    public cell()
    {
        T= -1;
        M= -1;
        s= false;
    }

    public cell(int T, int M)
    {
        this.T= T;
        this.M= M;
        this.s= false;
    }

    int T;
    int M;
    bool s;
}
```

And this "matrix":

```
cell[,] test = new cell[10, 4];
```

I need then to access the field of my class cell and I tried this:

```
for (var i = startR; i < nR; i++)
{
    for (var j = startR; j < nC; j++)
    {
        var p = test[i, j];

    }
}
```

But if I try `p.s` or `p.T` or `p.M` I can't see these attributes. Why? How can I access these fields?

Comment: Change accessability of the class and fields inside to `public` default for the [tag:c#] is `private` which you cannot access from outside of that classes scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields are `private` (`private`  is default access modifier inside class). Make all fields `public`:

```
public int T;
public int M;
public bool s;
```

Or better way

You can change fields to `public` auto properties (because fields should not be `public`):

```
public int T { get; set;}
public int M { get; set;}
public bool s { get; set;}
```

Or

If you want fields and properties:

```
int T;
int M;
bool s;

public int TProperty
{
    get {return T;}
    set {T = value;}
}

public int MProperty
{
    get {return M;}
    set {M = value;}
}

public bool SProperty
{
    get {return s;}
    set {s = value;}
}
```

Then to read or write simply use these properties:

```
var p = test[i, j];

var m = p.MProperty;
p.TProperty = 5;
```

Comment: What are the differences between your first and second solution?

Comment: Both solutions will work, but fields should not be public (first solution) so, I converted them to public properties.

Comment: @PieroAlberto More detailed answer for your comment would be that properties are just methods that wraps around certain field so you can have more control over the value passed to the backing field of that property. The thing is that in these 2 cases there's almost no difference ( other than to set value you will have another jump in the stack ).

Answer (score 0):

You can create public readonly auto properties, eg. like in the following example:

```
class cell
{
    public cell()
    {
        T = -1;
        M = -1;
        S = false;
    }

    public cell(int t, int m)
    {
        T = t;
        M = m;
        S = false;
    }

    public int T { get; }

    public int M { get; }

    public bool S { get; }
}
```

Setting values from the constructor (as you've already done) and using readonly properties is usually a better option than exposing public setters (unless you have a good reason to do so), as your instances of the `cell` class will be immutable and won't be changed after the instantiation.

Comment: You should mention that these properties will work only with [tag:C#] 6.0+.`'cell.T.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.`